# Tensorflow model not training when changing the input data

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to use tensorflow to train a neural network (LeNet) using the traffic sign images.  I want to check the effect of a preprocessing technique on the performance of the nn. So, I preprocessed the images and stored the results (trainingimages, validationimages,testimages, final testimages) as a tuple in a dict.

I then tried to iterate over this dict and then use the training and validation operations of the tensorflow as follows

```
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.utils import shuffle


output_data = []
EPOCHS = 5
BATCH_SIZE = 128
rate = 0.0005

for key in finalInputdata.keys():
    for procTypes in range(0,(len(finalInputdata[key]))):
        if np.shape(finalInputdata[key][procTypes][0]) != ():
            X_train = finalInputdata[key][procTypes][0]
            X_valid = finalInputdata[key][procTypes][1]
            X_test = finalInputdata[key][procTypes][2]
            X_finaltest = finalInputdata[key][procTypes][3]


            x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 32, 32,np.shape(X_train)[-1]))
            y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, (None))
            one_hot_y = tf.one_hot(y,43)

            # Tensor Operations
            logits = LeNet(x,np.shape(X_train)[-1])

            cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits,one_hot_y)
            softmax_probability = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

            loss_operation = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
            optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=rate)
            training_operation = optimizer.minimize(loss_operation)
            correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits,1), tf.argmax(one_hot_y,1))
            accuracy_operation = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))


                # Pipeline for training and evaluation

            sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

            sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
            num_examples = len(X_train)

            print("Training on %s images processed as %s" %(key,dict_fornames['proctypes'][procTypes]))
            print()
            for i in range(EPOCHS):
                X_train, y_train = shuffle(X_train, y_train)
                for offset in range(0, num_examples, BATCH_SIZE):
                    end = offset + BATCH_SIZE
                    batch_x, batch_y = X_train[offset:end], y_train[offset:end]
                    sess.run(training_operation, feed_dict = {x: batch_x, y: batch_y})

                training_accuracy = evaluate(X_train,y_train)

                validation_accuracy = evaluate(X_valid, y_valid)

                testing_accuracy = evaluate(X_test, y_test)

                final_accuracy = evaluate(X_finaltest, y_finalTest)

                print("EPOCH {} ...".format(i+1))
                print("Training Accuracy = {:.3f}".format(training_accuracy))
                print("Validation Accuracy = {:.3f}".format(validation_accuracy))
                print()
                output_data.append({'EPOCHS':EPOCHS, 'LearningRate':rate, 'ImageType': 'RGB',\
                                    'PreprocType': dict_fornames['proctypes'][0],\
                                    'TrainingAccuracy':training_accuracy, 'ValidationAccuracy':validation_accuracy, \
                                    'TestingAccuracy': testing_accuracy})


            sess.close()
```

The evaluate function is as follows

```
def evaluate(X_data, y_data):
    num_examples = len(X_data)
    total_accuracy = 0
    sess = tf.get_default_session()
    for offset in range(0,num_examples, BATCH_SIZE):
        batch_x, batch_y = X_data[offset:offset+BATCH_SIZE], y_data[offset:offset+BATCH_SIZE]
        accuracy = sess.run(accuracy_operation, feed_dict = {x:batch_x, y:batch_y})
        total_accuracy += (accuracy * len(batch_x))
    return total_accuracy / num_examples
```

Once I execute the program, it works good for the first iteration of dataset but from the second iteration, the network doesnt train and continues to do so for all the other iterations.

```
Training on RGB images processed as Original

EPOCH 1 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.525
Validation Accuracy = 0.474

EPOCH 2 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.763
Validation Accuracy = 0.682

EPOCH 3 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.844
Validation Accuracy = 0.723

EPOCH 4 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.888
Validation Accuracy = 0.779

EPOCH 5 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.913
Validation Accuracy = 0.795

Training on RGB images processed as Mean Subtracted Data

EPOCH 1 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.056
Validation Accuracy = 0.057

EPOCH 2 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.057
Validation Accuracy = 0.057

EPOCH 3 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.057
Validation Accuracy = 0.056

EPOCH 4 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.058
Validation Accuracy = 0.056

EPOCH 5 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.058
Validation Accuracy = 0.058

Training on RGB images processed as Normalized Data

EPOCH 1 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.058
Validation Accuracy = 0.054

EPOCH 2 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.058
Validation Accuracy = 0.054

EPOCH 3 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.058
Validation Accuracy = 0.054

EPOCH 4 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.058
Validation Accuracy = 0.054

EPOCH 5 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.058
Validation Accuracy = 0.054
```

However, if I restart the kernel and use any datatype (any iteration), it works. I figured out that I must clear the graph or run multiple sessions for multiple datatypes but I am not yet clear on how to do that. I tried using `tf.reset_default_graph()` but seems like it does not have any effect. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Could you be more specific about what the problem is?

Comment: As I already mentioned in the title, the network doesn't train. The training accuracy stands still at 0.05 even after many iterations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to make try with data that is normalized to zero mean and unit variance before feeding it to the network, e.g. by scaling images to `-1..1` range; that said, `0..1` range mostly sounds sane as well. Depending on the activations used in the network, the value range can make all the difference: ReLUs, for example, die out for inputs below zero, sigmoids start to saturate when values are below `-4` or above `+4` and tanh activations miss out on half of their value range if no value is ever below `0` - if the value range is too big, gradients may explode as well, preventing training altogether. From [this paper](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/sermanet-ijcnn-11.pdf), the authors seem to subtract the (batch) image mean instead of the value range mean.

You can try to use a *smaller* learning rate as well (although personally, I usually start experimenting around `0.0001` for Adam).

As for your multiple sessions part of the question: The way it is currently implemented in your code, you are basically cluttering the default graph. By calling

```
for key in finalInputdata.keys():
    for procTypes in range(0,(len(finalInputdata[key]))):
        if np.shape(finalInputdata[key][procTypes][0]) != ():

    # ...

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 32, 32,np.shape(X_train)[-1]))
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, (None))
    one_hot_y = tf.one_hot(y,43)

    # Tensor Operations
    logits = LeNet(x,np.shape(X_train)[-1])

    # ... etc ...
```

you are creating `len(finalInputdata) * N` *different* instances of LeNet, all within the default graph. That might be an issue when variables are internally reused in the network.

If you do want to reset your *default* graph in order to try different hyperparameters, try

```
for key in finalInputdata.keys():
    for procTypes in range(0,(len(finalInputdata[key]))):

        tf.reset_default_graph()
        # define the graph

        sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
        # train
```

but it is probably better to explictly create Graphs and Sessions like so:

```
for key in finalInputdata.keys():
    for procTypes in range(0,(len(finalInputdata[key]))):

        with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
            # define the graph

        with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
            # train
```

Instead of calling `sess = tf.get_default_session()` you would then directly use the `sess` reference.

I also found that Jupyter kernels and GPU enabled TensorFlow don't play together that well when iterating on networks, sometimes running into out of memory errors or downright crashing the browser tab.